# Как в Postgresql реализовать поиск по первым символам каждого слова в строке?

Tags: java, sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

На ввод подаются строки. Например: "**один**".
Запрос в базу должен матчить записи типа "три два **один**", "**один**надцатый", но не должен матчить записи типа "иван р**один**"

Возможно ли реализовать такое в SQL запросе? Или придется прибегать к логике кода? И может ли здесь помочь ElasticSearch?

На текущий момент поиск реализован по любому совпадению символов:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT m.id, m.name FROM table m WHERE name ILIKE %:query%", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Используйте regex в конструкции where https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945477/using-regex-in-where-in-postgres

Comment: да Elastic Search может помочь, т.к. он сможет сделать такой поиск эффективно, в то время как регулярки и запросы `like '%xyz%'` будут работать полным перебором. Впрочем полнотекстовый поиск бывает доступен как опция в некоторых реляционных СУБД. Но иногда проще сразу уже заюзать эластик, чем конфигурить встроенные опции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вы хотите найти строки, которые содержат слова, начинающиеся на определенную строку.

Для этого в PostgreSQL можно использовать оператор `~` и [соответствующее регулярное выражение с `'\m'`, обозначающим начало слова](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)`

```sql
select * from tbl where name ~ '\mодин'
```

В Java-коде соответственно:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT m.id, m.name FROM table m WHERE name ~ CONCAT('\\m', :query)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите искать только полные слова, а не искать их внутри других слов, можете попробовать составить свой SQL-запрос таким образом:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name FROM table m WHERE CONCAT(' ', name) LIKE '% :query %'
```

Здесь мы добавляем пробел перед значением `name`, и ищем пробел и `:query` внутри этой строки, таким образом будут искаться только полные слова.

Comment: Второй пробел ТС не нужен

Comment: Точно, чуть-чуть ошибся, исправил